# Adjektivendungen ohne Artikel

Tags: grammaticality

Ich habe eine Frage bezüglich der Adjektivendungen, wenn es keinen Artikel gibt und zwar welcher der beiden folgenden Sätze ist richtig und warum?

"Der Missbrauch anvertrautes Geldes"
 oder
"Der Missbrauch anvertrauten Geldes"

Comment: Hallo Katerina, willkommen bei German.SE! Danke für deine erste Frage. Es ist hier üblich, in Fragen und Antworten kein »Hallo« und »Danke« zu schreiben oder mit dem Namen zu unterschreiben. Mehr erfährst du im Help Center, insbesondere [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score 5):

Die Endung orientiert sich sowohl am Geschlecht (Genus) als auch am Fall (Kasus).

In diesem Falle handelt es sich um das Geld und steht im Genitiv. Du könntest auch sagen:

> > Der Missbrauch (des) anvertrauten Geldes.

Daher ist nur deine zweite Form richtig, die erste ist grammatikalisch falsch, wird aber trotzdem verstanden werden

Comment: Danke! Ich dachte, dass der Adjektiv in diesem Fall die Endung des fehlenden Artikels (nämlich -es) haben muss. Deswegen habe ich "Der Missbrauch anvertrautes Geldes" geschrieben. Wahrscheinlich ist "Der Missbrauch anvertrauten Geldes" stattdessen richtig, weil der Nomen (Geld) die Endung des fehlendes Artikels hat (?)